# How to generate 2 column data in a .CSV file using the 1st column data in power shell

Tags: powershell

If I have a .CSV where I am only given the 1st column values, it generates, using a formula, the 2nd column and the 3rd column is generated from the values of the 2nd column. I need to execute once to extract the 3 columns at once using powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Then .. do that

```
$text = @'
a,b,c
1,,
2,,
'@

$text | ConvertFrom-Csv | ForEach-Object {

    # calculate new value of column b using value of column a
    $_.b = [int]$_.a*2

    # calculate new value of column c using value of column b
    $_.c = $_.b * 2

    # output the row
    $_
}
```

Except, use `Import-Csv` instead of text and convert.